# How can I either reset the coordinates of this Buffered Image or put this Buffered Image in the rectangle?

Tags: java

I imported this "troll face" into my code as my enemy which rains from top of the screen to the bottom. But before doing so I created the pink rectangles so that I can overlay the troll face image on top of the rectangles. However, when I set the coordinates of the image equal to the rectangle, you can see that it did not center. I then set one troll face image's coordinate equal to (0,0) and you can see that it is clearly far away from the origin.

I tried to import a different PNG image but in vain and it did not work.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class magazinerain extends GameDriverV4{
    LinkedList<rainingenemies> r = new LinkedList<rainingenemies>();
    rainingenemies variable;
    BufferedImage trollface;

    public magazinerain() {
        trollface = this.addImage("minion.png");
    }
    public void faller(Graphics2D win) {
        for (int i = 0; i<r.size(); i++) {
            variable=r.get(i);
            variable.fall(win);
            if (variable.getY()>=800) {
                delete(variable);
            }

        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D win) {
        int count = 0;
        win.drawImage(trollface, 0, 0,null);
        for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
            variable = r.get(i);
            variable.fall(win);
            //win.drawImage(trollface, (int) variable.getX(), (int) variable.getY(),null);
            //the images are not correctly centered on the screen
            //win.drawImage(trollface, 400, 400,null);
        }
    }
    public void memorymanagement() {
        for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
            variable = r.get(i);
            //System.out.println(variable.getY());
            if (variable.getY()>=800) {
                r.remove(i);
                //System.out.println("Removed");
            }

        }
    }

    public void checkintersects(int a, int b) {
        int buffer = 10;
        int buffery = 15;
        for (int i = 0; i< r.size(); i++) {
            variable  = r.get(i);
            //if (a>(variable.getX()-buffer) && (a<variable.getX()+buffer)) {
            if ((variable.getX()>a-buffer-10)&& (variable.getX()<a+buffer+30)) {
                //if ((b>variable.getY()-buffery) && (b<variable.getX()+buffery)) {
                if ((variable.getY()>b-buffery) && (variable.getY()<b+buffery)){
                    r.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("spacex="+a+"getx="+variable.getX());
                    System.out.println("spacey="+b+"gety="+variable.getY());

                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void delete(rainingenemies a) {
        r.remove(a);
    }
    public void insert(rainingenemies a) {
        r.add(a);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Specifically in this code, I expected the troll face to be at (0,0) but it is not there as shown in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: My guess is that your troll face **file** has a bunch of transparent white space surrounding it, and that is throwing off your calculations.

Comment: What makes you think that it is NOT at 0,0? It looks to me that it could be, if the reference pixel is lower left of the face and 0,0 in the middle of the picture. Especially if parts of the face are transparent (i.e. agreeing with @Dylan).